# org.fest.reflect.exception.ReflectionError: Unable to find method '$$robo$getData' in com.android.myActivity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, robolectric

I am using robolectric for android automation testing with ant build using eclipse when i am trying to exucute the given line of code

```
 Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class).create().visible().get(); throwing org.fest.reflect.exception.ReflectionError: Unable to find method '$$robo$getData error
```

I am using following Libraries in my lib folder

```
Used library 
fest-android-1.0.8.jar
fest-assert-core-2.0M10.jar
fest-util-1.1.6.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
junit-4.11-sources.jar
junit-4.11.jar
mockito-core-1.9.5.jar
robolectric-2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar
robolectric-with-dependencies.jar(Used for creating a test runner class  for ant and eclipse build)
```

after removing robolectric-with-dependencies.jar i am getting

```
  [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar
:1.2' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/)
: Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:jar:20080701' from r
epository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/): Error tran
sferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.
3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Err
or transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.jar from
 repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
    [junit] Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar from repositor
y central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar
:1.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferrin
g file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:jar:20080701' from r
epository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo
1.maven.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/androi
d-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar from repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.
org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.jar from
 repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar from repositor
y sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.
3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/g
roups/public/): Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:jar:20080701' from r
epository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/): Error tran
sferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar
:1.2' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/)
: Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/androi
d-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org
/maven2
    [junit] Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.jar from
 repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
    [junit] Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar from repositor
y central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar
:1.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferrin
g file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:jar:20080701' from r
epository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo
1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.
3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Err
or transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar from repositor
y sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/androi
d-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar from repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.
org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.jar from
 repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:jar:20080701' from r
epository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/): Error tran
sferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.
3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/g
roups/public/): Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar from repositor
y central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar
:1.2' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/)
: Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/androi
d-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org
/maven2
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.jar from
 repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:jar:20080701' from r
epository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo
1.maven.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.
3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Err
or transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar
:1.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferrin
g file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 9, Time elapsed: 0.087 sec
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.tracker.SignInDialogTest FAILED
    [junit] Running com.pivotallabs.tracker.TrackerAuthenticationRequestTest
    [junit] Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar from repositor
y sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.jar from
 repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/androi
d-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar from repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.
org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar
:1.2' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/)
: Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.
3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/g
roups/public/): Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:jar:20080701' from r
epository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/): Error tran
sferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.jar from
 repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
    [junit] Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar from repositor
y central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar
:1.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferrin
g file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/androi
d-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org
/maven2
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:jar:20080701' from r
epository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo
1.maven.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.
3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Err
or transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar from repositor
y sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/androi
d-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar from repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.
org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.jar from
 repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.
3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/g
roups/public/): Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:jar:20080701' from r
epository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/): Error tran
sferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/androi
d-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org
/maven2
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar
:1.2' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/)
: Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar from repositor
y central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.jar from
 repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.
3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Err
or transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar
:1.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferrin
g file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:jar:20080701' from r
epository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo
1.maven.org
    [junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Time elapsed: 0.022 sec
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.tracker.TrackerAuthenticationRequestTest FAILED

    [junit] Running com.pivotallabs.util.StringsTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
    [junit] Running com.pivotallabs.views.LoadingTextViewTest
    [junit] Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar from repositor
y sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/androi
d-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar from repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.
org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.jar from
 repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:jar:20080701' from r
epository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/): Error tran
sferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.
3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/g
roups/public/): Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar
:1.2' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/)
: Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar from repositor
y central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
    [junit] Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/androi
d-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org
/maven2
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.jar from
 repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:jar:20080701' from r
epository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo
1.maven.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.
3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Err
or transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar
:1.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferrin
g file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar from repositor
y sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/androi
d-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar from repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.
org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.jar from
 repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:jar:20080701' from r
epository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/): Error tran
sferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.
3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/g
roups/public/): Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar from repositor
y central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar
:1.2' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/)
: Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/androi
d-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org
/maven2
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Downloading: org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2/tagsoup-1.2.jar from
 repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.json:json:jar:20080701' from r
epository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo
1.maven.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:4.
3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Err
or transferring file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar
:1.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferrin
g file: repo1.maven.org
    [junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Time elapsed: 0.017 sec
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.views.LoadingTextViewTest FAILED

BUILD FAILED
D:\Robolectric(SetUp)\New folder\robolectric-ant-sample-master\custom_rules.xml:
58: Unit test(s) failed.  See reports!

Total time: 9 seconds
```

It seems its trying to download something from maven repo but i am not using it.

Comment: Has robolectric-with-dependencies.jar version 2.3?

Comment: Yes i am using which i have mentioned in robolectric-2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar in used lib section.

Comment: Why do you have it twice?

Comment: Becoz i am using the ruuner class from that jar...is there any issue for that.

Comment: It can lead to conflict when using 2 versions of the same library, because some classes can be loaded from one jar and some from another. You should avoid such situation.

Comment: Yes i have removed the old robolectric-with-dependencies.jar now i am getting error see my edited question.

Comment: What, when you remove robolectric-2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar and live robolectric-with-dependencies.jar?

Comment: i only removed the  robolectric-with-dependencies.jar